# random numbers with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to practice on using AJAX. I have a MySQL database, and I have inserted some names in the column storeName. I made a SQL query that output random text in column in the database. That is working fine, but only when I refresh my browser:

```
<?php
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM stores ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 1";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    //print($res);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Storename: " . $row["storeName"]. "<br>" .     
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

I would like to make an AJAX function, that calls my SQL query without I have to refresh my browser. I tried to make the following code, but when I hit the shuffle button, nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<body>
<div id="shuffle" >
  <h4>Shuffle Stores</h4>
    <!-- This php function loads everytime I refresh the browser -->
    <?php include 'function/select_shuffle.php' ?>

      <form action="function/select_shuffle.php" method="post">
        <button>shuffle</button>
      </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Shuffle AJAX method-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({url: "function/select_shuffle.php", success: function(result){
                    $("#shuffle").html(result);
                }});
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

[image: AJAX]

@Sehdev:
[image: AJAX_1]

Comment: Is the success callback being called?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. No that is not called. Actually I can see now, that when I hit the button "Shuffle", I get the error `localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: You aren't preventing the form from submitting through default process.

Comment: I tried with `post | get`, but same result.

Comment: Why do you have a form?

Comment: The submit button needs to be inside a form element for the document to be valid X/HTML, as far as I know.

Comment: that is false. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: If I make the code like this my problem is solved: `<form method="post">
     <button>shuffle</button>
    </form>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to include select_shuffle.php file in your current page if you are making an ajax call.

Please try the following code. Also you can check your console for any ajax error. Right click on your page and choose Inspect. Then click on "Network" tab and after that click on XHR heading. Here you can track your ajax request. You can check header, response or any ajax error.

```
<body>
<div id="shuffle" >
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Shuffle Stores</h4>
      <button id="btn">shuffle</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Shuffle AJAX method-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "function/select_shuffle.php", 
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        $("#shuffle").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Nice I did not know that with the XHR heading. I just tried with your code, but I am getting the same error. I uploaded a screenshot with the XHR heading in my question.

Comment: can you just click on select_shuffle.php and post screen shots of headers and response tabs ( open on right side when you will click on that file)

Comment: Thank you again. I just posted a picture of headers. In the response tab there is nothing except the text: "The response has no data avaible"

Comment: `<form method="post">
     <button>shuffle</button>
    </form>` . How can that be?

Comment: Try this code in your select_shuffle file. Also try to execute this file directly in your browser whether you will get 500 internal server error or not.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM stores ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Storename: '". $row['storeName']."'<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

Answer (score -1):

Error 500 means Internal Server Error.

Change

```
echo "Storename: ".$row["storeName"]."<br>" .
```

To

```
echo "Storename: ".$row["storeName"]."<br>";
```

Submit button must be in form but button that triggers only ajax have no reason to be in form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added the `;`, but still gives the exact same error.

Comment: In devtools click on red URL and look at Preview tab. What is there?

Comment: I just uploaded a picture with more details of the 500 error.